# List of Elements that are editable in Salesforce Production Environment

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, deployment, metadata-api, production

Is there an article or a document by Salesforce where I can find a comprehensive list of elements or types that can be modified in Salesforce Production Environment?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you're talking about the various types of metadata, the only five types you can't edit in production are Lightning Web Components, Aura Components, Visualforce Pages, Visualforce Components, and Apex Code. All other types of metadata can be edited under correct circumstances (e.g. you can't edit an Activated Process Builder, but you can clone to create a new one).

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox! Yes I was referring to metadata types.